# URL validation seems broken

Tags: validation, url, go

I'm trying to validate a URL using Go's standard library. This is what my code currently looks like.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func isValidURL(tocheck string) bool {
    _, err := url.ParseRequestURI(tocheck)
    return err == nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(isValidURL("google.com"))      //returns false, expected true
    fmt.Println(isValidURL("www.google.com"))  //returns false, expected true
    fmt.Println(isValidURL("google"))          //returns false, expected false
    fmt.Println(isValidURL("/google"))         //returns true, expected false
}
```

All three examples print false, even though the first two should be true. I then tried appending `https://` to the beginning of URLs that don't start with them, but then everything, like `https://aaaa` is parsed as valid. What can I do to make sure it only returns true when the URL is actually valid?

Comment: Why do you think that `https://aaaa` is not valid yet `https://google` is valid? What about `https://localhost`?

Comment: `https://google` is not valid

Comment: `https://google` is a valid URL. The validity of a URL has nothing to do with whether or not the domain or path actually exists (which is something that can change over time, unlike URL validity, which can only change by an update to the URL spec).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have confused domains with URLs, the domain is only a part of the URL.

Valid domain examples are: `www.google.com`, `localhost` and `a.b.c.a.google.com`.

In order for a URL to be valid the scheme/protocol part (normally `https://`) must be there, see [syntax at Wikipedia for an easy explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax).

`http://aaa` is a valid URL by the same rules as `http://localhost` is valid

Comment: I'm trying to validate URLs that can be redirected to and therefore `http://aaa` clearly should not be valid.

Comment: If a URL is valid and if the URL actually leads to something that works is two different things.

Comment: And indeed requires actually testing it and changes with execution context and over time. On one machine, `http://localhost/foo/bar` might yield a response, and on another, it might not. Likewise, on the machine where it yields a response, it might not a minute later (if a file is removed or a service is stopped). URL/URI validity is a question of valid *syntax*, not fitness for any other purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Most of those are domain names. `https://aaaa` is a valid URL. `/google` is not a URL, but it is acceptable to [`ParseRequestURI`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseRequestURI) because it also accepts absolute paths.

> "*rawurl is interpreted only as an absolute URI* ***or an absolute path***"

When you ask `ParseRequestURI` you're asking for a strict syntax check of either an absolute URL or an absolute path. An absolute path is anything like `/foo/bar`. What is and is not an absolute URL is covered by [RFC 3986](https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986). The basic grammar for a URI is this.

```
URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
            / path-absolute
            / path-rootless
            / path-empty
```

An "absolute URL" means the `path` part is an absolute path or empty, so `path-abempty` or `path-absolute` above. `http` and `https` URLs can only be absolute. `foo:bar/baz` is an example of a relative URL.

And here's an example.

```
  foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
   |           |            |            |        |
scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
   |   _____________________|__
  / \ /                        \
  urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

`google.com` has no `scheme`, so it is not a URL. `https://aaaa` has a scheme, `https` and a `hier-part`, `//aaaa`, so it is a URL. It doesn't have a `query` or `fragement`, but they are optional.

Obviously this is a bit broad. In the real world you need to narrow down your requirements. Usually it's something like...

1. Validate it is a URL, which you're not quite doing by calling `ParseRequestURI` because it can also be an absolute path.
2. Check it has an acceptable scheme, `url.Scheme`. This will discard absolute paths.
3. Check it has a valid domain name, `url.Host`.

And any other checks you might want to do to restrict what you consider to be a valid URL.

So your full check might look like...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/url"
    "errors"
)

func isValidURL(tocheck string) (bool, error) {
    // Check it's an Absolute URL or absolute path
    uri, err := url.ParseRequestURI(tocheck)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    // Check it's an acceptable scheme
    switch uri.Scheme {
        case "http":
        case "https":
        default:
            return false, errors.New("Invalid scheme")
    }

    // Check it's a valid domain name
    _,err = net.LookupHost(uri.Host)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}

func main() {
    // False, no scheme
    fmt.Println(isValidURL("/google"))
    // True, good scheme, good domain
    fmt.Println(isValidURL("https://google.com"))
    // False, bad domain
    fmt.Println(isValidURL("http://halghalghlakdjfl.blarg"))
}
```

Comment: The second link returns false.

Comment: @ninesalt Works For Me™ It should tell you why it returned false.

Comment: @ninesalt `net.LookupHost` requires making a network connection to a DNS server. I'm going to assume play.golang.org doesn't allow that for security reasons. For example, `fmt.Println( http.Get("http://example.com/") )` says `<nil> Get http://example.com/: dial tcp: Protocol not available`. It'll work on a real machine with a network connection.